# Destacar menu "Blog" quando acessar uma categoria ou post

Tags: php, wordpress

Tenho um site wordpress e gostaria que assim como fica selecionado o menu de acordo com a página que estou, também fique selecionado o item "Blog" do menu quando eu estiver em uma página de categoria ou em um post.

Esse é o código do menu do meu tema:

```
$defaults = array(
    'container'         => 'nav',
    'theme_location'    => 'primary',
    'depth'             => 3,
    'walker'            => new ts_walker_nav_menu
    );
wp_nav_menu( $defaults ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por padrão o wordpress coloca a class ".current-menu-item" no item que está selecionado no menu, tente estilizar essa class no seu css.

Mas se entendi bem a pergunta, você precisa que o menu "blog" também fique destacado, você precisará de um teste, pois a função de nav não vai identificar automaticamente que o blog está ativo, ja que vai retornar o item da categoria como ativo.

Comment: Então, será que vc saberia me dizer onde encontro essa função do nav que atribui a class current-menu-item no item ativo? Ai eu poderia tentar encaixar a condição de também destacar o "blog" quando estiver em alguma categoria ou post.

Comment: ele coloca a class por padrão